# Redis - keys, expression

Tags: redis

I use Redis and ruby. There are records:

```
"phones:initial:#{id}"

redis.hset "phones:initial:1", "query", query
redis.hset "phones:initial:2", "query", query
redis.hset "phones:initial:3", "query", query
redis.hset "phones:initial:4", "query", query
...
```

is it possible to get the keys, in which id corresponds to a expression?

```
"phones:initial: and id % m = n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, there's no built-in method to do that. You have to use the `SCAN` command to iterate on all keys, and select those that match the given pattern.

However, if you always use the same `m` for the expression, you can pre-compute `n` for each `id`, and make `n` as a part of the key. In this way, you can use Redis' pattern match to get those specific keys.

For example, suppose `m == 2`, you can have the following new keys: `phones:initial:1:1`, `phones:initial:0:2`, `phones:initial:1:3`, `phones:initial:0:4`. To get keys that match `phones:initial: and id % 2 == 0`, use the following command: `SCAN 0 MATCH phones:initial:0:*`